# Using asp.net site.master and spark views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Is it possible to use my site.master master page ? I want to start using Spark more, but this project I am working on is using asp.net view pages as well.

I could of course convert the master page to an application.spark page, but I was wondering if it is at all possible to use the Site.Master I already have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember, had no problems with this. There are questions in stack that says there are.

Scenario that will work for sure - double your site.master in spark (make 2 master pages).

Comment: Yes, if you keep the master page somewhat simple and static and use partials to render stuff like a menu, it's not too bad.

Comment: Migrating to spark doesn't take long anyway. So - keeping 2 masterpages is just a temporary solution.